# How to get timezone name in different language C# on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am currently getting TimeZone using

```
 string TimeZoneName = "Indian Standard Time";
 var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneName);
```

It is currently returning the desired value in English even if I change the Current culture and I am currently testing the code on Azure (Web App Service). Please help me to find a  way in which I can get the code to return value in Different language like Arabic, French, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().SingleOrDefault(z => z.DaylightName == TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName);
```

This will return the current timezone based on the OS language.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the nuget package : 
https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames

> PM> Install-Package TimeZoneNames

It' a simple library that provides localized time zone names using CLDR and TZDB sources.

Example:

```
var names = TZNames.GetNamesForTimeZone("Romance Standard Time", "en-GB");

names.Generic == "Central European Time"
names.Standard == "Central European Standard Time"
names.Daylight == "Central European Summer Time"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not dealing with a NAME, but an ID.

> TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById

Read the method name. It does not say "by name" but "by id". The ID is meant to be the same across all languages.

What you can do is go across all timezones and compared names (Display Name) likely, then take the one you want. The names is localized:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.displayname(v=vs.110).aspx

> The display name is localized based on the culture installed with the
>   Windows operating system.

But the ID does not never ever change. On purpose.

Comment: I am passing the ID to get the details and later I am using Display name in my Solution. I am also aware that it is OS dependent. My question is that how can I get the Display name in Arabic on azure Web app when I change culture of my app from English to Arabic

Comment: No, sorry, this is NOT THE QUESTION YOU ASKED.

Comment: In the Question I specified that I am using azure web app service for testing so expected the answer would be related to azure. I have tagged it with azure and azure web sites as well